# FreeSWITCH : Is there a way to get the audio stream from other leg via the native API

Tags: c#, c++, file, audio, freeswitch

I am using Microsoft speech with FreeSWITCH. I want to read the audio stream from FreeSWITCH and send it over to the Speech engine. Is there any way in the native API to get the audio stream. Or to read it and then I can manually stream it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of ways to activate eavesdropping. Search for eavesdrop in FreeSWITCH documentation.

Comment: My problem is that I need the audio to be accessible from my .net module. I am handling everything else from there. Right now, I am recording the sound and then I read it as file. If I could directly get it via the API, I can then use it in my app.

Comment: You can use eavesdrop to get a copy of the stream, and then push it to your application via http. I can help you building a prototype if there is a budget.

Comment: Can we discuss the budget, Hourly rate and the time required. We will see if we can afford that. :)

Comment: skype: ssinyagin  or see my contacts in G+